# printing in web without displaying a print dialog

Tags: php, jquery, printing

Is there another way to print in web without showing the print dialog I came across [this](https://www.neodynamic.com/articles/Print-PDF-from-PHP-directly-to-default-printer-without-print-dialog/) but it requires to install **Download & install WebClientPrint for PHP** I am wondering is there a way to do this but using the default settings. I mean no 3rd party installation.

What i have are :

1. jquery
2. FPDF to create a pdf of what i need to print

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this, because you are bound by the client, and all browsers do not let you to bypass the print dialog.

If your server knows the printer that the client will use, you can make an API endpoint on your server that makes your server send the print command to the printer.

Comment: what do you call the process the does this i want to search more on this. since i dont know what this is i cant search for anything

Comment: @Giant You mean the server method? It's completely platform- and device-dependant, but I assume that it would go something like: 1) Receive HTTP request 2) Send system command to start print job

Comment: what exactly should i search for sending printing request ? i have fpdf. the fpdf is the one i need to print